# Image rectification algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I have recently found an interesting article regarding image rectification for two stereo image pairs. I liked the algorithm because it was very compact and from what the article suggested it did the right thing. After I implemented the matlab version on two images, I didn't get a correct rectified image. I got an image that was pitch black apart from the left and down line which had pixels. In the image there also were some gray pixels from the original image but just a hand full. I posted below the matlab code, and the link to the article and also an example of the result I got for one image (for the other image it was the same)

This is the link to the article [A compact algorithm for rectification of stereo pairs](http://qh.eng.ua.edu/classes/spring2007/ece635/index_files/papers/compact_algorithm_rectification.pdf).

A screen shot with the initial images and the results is bellow:
[image: screen shot]

The initial images are the following two(such that you do not have to search for another stereo pair) : [image: stereo image 1 here] [image: stereo image two here]

```
function [T1,T2,Pn1,Pn2] = rectify(Po1,Po2)

% RECTIFY: compute rectification matrices 

% factorize old PPMs
[A1,R1,t1] = art(Po1);
[A2,R2,t2] = art(Po2);

 % optical centers (unchanged)
c1 = - inv(Po1(:,1:3))*Po1(:,4);
c2 = - inv(Po2(:,1:3))*Po2(:,4);

% new x axis (= direction of the baseline)
 v1 = (c1-c2);
% new y axes (orthogonal to new x and old z)
v2 = cross(R1(3,:)',v1);
% new z axes (orthogonal to baseline and y)
v3 = cross(v1,v2);

% new extrinsic parameters 
R = [v1'/norm(v1)
   v2'/norm(v2)
   v3'/norm(v3)];
% translation is left unchanged

% new intrinsic parameters (arbitrary) 
A = (A1 + A2)./2;
A(1,2)=0; % no skew
A(1,3) = A(1,3) + 160;
% new projection matrices
Pn1 = A * [R -R*c1 ];
Pn2 = A * [R -R*c2 ];

% rectifying image transformation
T1 = Pn1(1:3,1:3)* inv(Po1(1:3,1:3));
T2 = Pn2(1:3,1:3)* inv(Po2(1:3,1:3));

function [A,R,t] = art(P)
% ART: factorize a PPM as  P=A*[R;t]
Q = inv(P(1:3, 1:3));
[U,B] = qr(Q);

R = inv(U);
t = B*P(1:3,4);
A = inv(B);
A = A ./A(3,3);
```

This is the "main" code from which I call my rectify function

```
img1 = imread('D:\imag1.png');
img2 = imread('D:\imag2.png');

im1 = rgb2gray(img1);
im2 = rgb2gray(img2);

im1 = im2double(im1);
im2 = im2double(im2);

figure; imshow(im1, 'border', 'tight')
figure; imshow(im2, 'border', 'tight')

%pair projection matrices obtained after the calibration P01,P02

a = double(9.765*(10^2))
b = double(5.790*(10^-1))
format bank;
Po1 = double([a 5.382*10 -2.398*(10^2) 3.875*(10^5); 
    9.849*10 9.333*(10^2) 1.574*(10^2) 2.428*(10^5);
    b 1.108*(10^(-1)) 8.077*(10^(-1)) 1.118*(10^3)]);
Po2 = [9.767*(10^2) 5.376*10 -2.400*(10^2) 4.003*(10^4);
    9.868*10 9.310*(10^2) 1.567*(10^2) 2.517*(10^5);
    5.766*(10^(-1)) 1.141*(10^(-1)) 8.089*(10^(-1)) 1.174*(10^3)];
[T1, T2, Pn1, Pn2] = rectify(Po1, Po2);

imnoua =  conv2(im1, T1);
imnoua2 = conv2(im2, T2);

fprintf('Imaginea noua e \n');

figure; imshow(imnoua, 'border', 'tight')
figure; imshow(imnoua2, 'border', 'tight')
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: why do you `conv` the image with `T`? shouldn't you use geometric transformation?

Answer (score 2):

As [Shai says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745809/image-rectification-algorithm-in-matlab#comment40256852_25745809), `T1` and `T2` are projective transformation matrices, not filter kernels. You should be using `imwarp`, rather than `conv2`:

```
imnoua = imwarp(im1, projective2d(T1));
imnoua2 = imwarp(im2, projective2d(T2));
```

Better yet, use `rectifyStereoImages` from the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  Check out this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. First of all I tried the solution with imwrap but it doesn't give me a rectified image, it just gives me a small dot on the screen. Second the reason why I don't want to use the predefiend Matlab functions is because after I fully understand what is going on in the rectification process I want to implement it on an embedded board :) To make a small stereo vision robot. The final implementeation will be in c++.

Comment: In that case, you seem to have some debugging to do. You can try `estimateUncalibratedRectification` to get an idea of what your projective matrices should look like.